# how to set the max length of webservice parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configure

the system's configuration is:

- web server: WEBrick
- software enviroment: ruby on rails

when the browser passes more than 400 bytes parameters to the server, the server returns 414 code(Request-URI Too Large).

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Bates answered your question here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/43

In short: use mongrel in development.

---

A few useful details:

The URI limits vary given client, server and even browser.

**Browsers**

IE has a limit around 2kb, firefox 65kb. Since Api are triggered from servers it's not that annoying.

**Servers**

Nginx's default limit is 4kb for 32bits and 8kb for 64bits.

Apache's default is 8190 bytes.

Both can be changed inside config.

*Source: the excellent 'Service Oriented Design with RoR'*